# GET String of UISearchController's scopeButtonTitles

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

Is it possible to get string of UISearchContoller's segment controls ?

We get index path of that in this way

```
searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex
```

But instead of indexPath, I want to get the String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
```